# No query results for model [App\Models\XXXX]

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm getting this error message when updating the data via the PUT method on Postman.

```
No query results for model [App\Models\Post].
```

Code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = $request->isMethod('put') ? Post::findOrFail
        ($request->post_id): new Post;

        $post->id= $request->input('id');
        $post->title= $request->input('title');
        $post->body= $request->input('body');

        if($post->save()){
            return response($post);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Reference: https://github.com/Devgroup-Asia/lumenblog/blob/main/app/Http/Controllers/PostsController.php

Comment: You are sending id, but asking for post_id in the controller. That way the findOrFail will not find a model for the value null. For the future, it is always good to debug what you THINK is right, and confirm that it is right. Always start by checking your own inputs and that the value is actually what you expect, do that by using the dd() helper. E.g. dd($request); would have told you the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to this below code.

```
 Post::findOrFail($request->post_id)
```

Post with $request->post_id doesnot found.
You may be missing to send post_id from form